# How do I set ubuntu to compress a series of folders , deleting the original after its been compressed?

Tags: bash, files, compression

I need to setup some kind of script to go through a set of folders, compressing each one, and only leaving the compressed copy of each. How can I do that?

Comment: The title doesn't pretty much say it. What do want to do exactly? Do you want a script that performs these actions? What type of archive do you want? What order do you want to execute?

Comment: To be exact I want to 1. compress a folder, 2. After it compresses that folder, delete that folder (Where the backup compressed file remains) 3. Pick the next folder on the list and repeat. I Suppose I do want a script.

Comment: How does the list with folders look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script takes a list of folders as arguments. Save it as e.g. `backup.sh` and call it like this:

```
./backup.sh Folder1 Folder2
```

You have to make the script executable before this:

```
chmod u+x backup.sh
```

Here comes the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for folder in "$@"
do
    tar czf $folder.tgz $folder
    rm -R $folder
done
```

Tell me if this is not what you need. If you are not sure what it's doing make a backup of your data before you test it ;-)

Comment: It did work. ty much.